# Ubuntu Microphone not detected

Tags: dual-boot, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I recently installed an Ubuntu alongside Windows via DualBoot. At the beginning everything was fine and my Ubuntu had no problem. Recently, however, my headset microphone is no longer recognized and I have spent hours on it. With Windows, however, it still works as usual. Alsamixer and all other programs like pavucontrol say that no microphone exists. But I can hear sound through my headset.

I thank you in advance for any help

Comment: What is already also tried is booting from different kernels. That did not work either